# ColdFusion and Oracle SQL Injection Example

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion, sql-injection

Assuming ColdFusion 10,0,13,287689 and Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production.

With this example...

```
<cfquery name="q" datasource="ds">
    update someTable set
    #form.col#label = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#x#">
    where id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal" value="#id#">
</cfquery>
```

Also assuming there is no data validation checking on `#form.col#`, how could this be exploited? Obviously they could cause the query to fail with an invalid column, but I don't see any way something more malicious could be done since multiple statements cannot be ran in a single `<cfquery>`.  So something like this does not work...

`#form.col#:`

```
id = 1; delete from users; --comment everything else out...
```

I'm aware that with SELECTs it's easier to exploit using unions to get data you're not authorized to see, but I'm curious about this specific update statement.

Comment: So... What are you asking?

Comment: Is it possible to exploit this?  I know I could make the query fail, but I'm not seeing how any other UPDATE, DELETE, or SELECT could be ran.

Comment: I could be wrong but would this be considered code review?

Comment: Is that a different stackoverflow site? ... I see it, thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the origin of variable x?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.  I'm moving it to codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Moved it here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/50935/coldfusion-oracle-sql-injection-example

Comment: _"since multiple statements cannot be ran in a single cfquery"_ - except for the times when they can?

Comment: I know how to with MySql, how with Oracle?

Comment: last time I checked, multiple statements in a single cfquery was only possible with mysql and sql server.  That was a few years back though.

Comment: Multiple statements in a single cfquery is possible with every SQL engine (regardless of any datasource settings CF has).

Comment: One example: pass the col variable as something like:
`public_column = (SELECT badly_encrypted_password FROM users WHERE username='admin' ), <original_value>` - then a later SELECT can be used to obtain the hash for the attacker to bruteforce/etc.

Comment: @PeterBoughton THAT'S what I was looking for! Thank you, I was able to maliciously get data from another table using that technique.  Post it as the answer if you want the points.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst the traditional example for SQL injection involves sequential SQL statements, that is only a simple example used to highlight the issue - if unprotected user-derived text is allowed anywhere in any query there's a chance an attacker will be able to make use of it.

In this specific example, your query is:

```
update someTable
set #form.col#label = ?
where id = ?`
```

To abuse that is simple - prefix a genuine `col` value with something like:

```
public_column = (SELECT badly_encrypted_password 
FROM users WHERE username='admin' ), <orig_value>
```

The resultant SQL is then:

```
update someTable
set public_column = ( SELECT badly_encrypted_password FROM users WHERE username='admin' )
  , <orig_value>label = ?
where id = ?`
```

Which of course sets the value of that column to the result of the sub-query, and then a separate select in another area would then innocently return the sensitive data.

Alternatively, an attacker may decide simply to deface/remove data using this method, and depending on what precisely Oracle's SQL syntax allows, other things might be possible.

Comment: Is there a way to protect against this other than doing a whole bunch of data validation on the `form.col`?